# Is there any known value for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I just became curious about this sequence, so I tried several method to get exact value of the sum.
I know it converges, but I have no idea to calculate the exact value.
Is the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n!}$ already known, or does any nice method for it exist?

Comment: Did you try telescoping sum? Not sure if that works or not. Wolfram Alpha gives the value to be $1.02607....$ , and that looks like an usual number

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that there is some nice characterization of the answer? Most convergent sums do not have closed-form expressions for their limits.